# Does nginx strip custom request headers?

Tags: nginx

In my nginx.conf I have this line in my server {} section:

```
log_format debug 'header: "$http_x_myapp" cookies: "$http_cookie"';
```

Then if I do

```
curl -H "X_MYAPP:test" -H "COOKIE:yay" localhost
```

I get something like this in my access log:

```
header: "-" cookies: "yay"
```

Does anyone know why nginx is throwing away the X_MYAPP header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops... I'm stupid.

```
curl -H "X-MYAPP:test" -H "COOKIE:yay" localhost
```

works... stupid underscores...

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to send cookies with curl is with the `-b` options:

```
curl -b 'yay' http://localhost
```